# Camel: How to synchronize competing imap consumers

Tags: apache-camel

I am looking to use apache-camel to poll an imap inbox, but I am wondering how this setup would behave in a cluster. I would deploy apache camel on each node of the cluster, and each node would poll the inbox.

How can I avoid having many consumers pick up the same message?

Comment: Hello, I will answer with a suggestion rather than an answer as I don't know your underlying architecture. I would use Apache James http://james.apache.org/ with JMS as an Intermediate layer. Each of the following Camel nodes should read the JMS message of the generated by JAMES queue. Or you could move your consumed messages to folders but this solution won't scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to take the simple road and not install additional components. I used a clustered quartz job to trigger the polling of the inbox. The poller then places a retrieval command on a Hazelcast distributed queue, which is received by an array of Message retrieval components in the cluster.

Installing,  Jms,  James,  in addition to Camel smelled to me, just to solve this task.

Comment: Yeah that works as well using clustered quartz. It can be used to trigger on a single active node. You may not need the hazelcast, as you can just run the polling on the same node as the quartz got triggered. But hazelcast can be used to distribute the work if you want more nodes to process the imap messages. So seems like you are on top of this.

Comment: as soon as I'm allowed to, I will. Still have to wait a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Not very easy, since imap is not really a protocol for these kind of tasks.

The trick is still to have one consumer do the polling, not many. If you have many nodes for high availablility, you could do some tricks with JMS to trigger IMAP polls.

For instance, you could use a jms trigger message to init a poll and have all members of the cluster listen to that poll. Keep the concurrentConsumer to 1 and async. JMS disabled in Camel. You can rely on Message Groups or [ActiveMQ exclusive consumer](http://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer.html) to be sure that only one node gets the trigger messages (when alive, otherwise another node will take over). Generating the polling messages might be tricky, but could be done as simply as a timer route from each camel node. Just tune the frequency.

This setup will avoid race conditions in IMAP, while not beeing load balanced, at least fail over secured. It might be good enough to just go ahead and do concurrent polling, with few issues. However, I don't think you will be 100% safe without only allowing one consumer.

Comment: Hi Petter, this approach looks like something I was thinking about, but don't know how to do. I wanted to use a hazelcast lock to synchronize all potential IMAP clients for a given inbox, but have no idea how to configure the routes in camel.

The idea would be to have a component that first obtains a lock in hazelcast, and then forwards a token to the IMAP component. This would alllow only one component in the cluster to connect to a given inbox at a time. Do you know how you would go about configuring the route?

Comment: Ahh.. that might work. Although I have never worked with hazelcast in Camel, so I'm not sure how that setup will look like. Claus answer looks like an elegant way to acomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

In a clustered environment you may consider having a way of electing a single Camel route that is active, which does the imap polling. And then have logic for failover if the node goes down.

In Camel you can take a look at route policy which can be applied to routes.
http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy

The zookeeper component has a policy for electing a leader in a cluster, and only allow one  route to be active. This requires though that you use zookeeper.
http://camel.apache.org/zookeeper